# List and arraylist initialization and use

Tags: java, arrays, list, arraylist

I'm attempting to create a list because of the ability to "add" and element as opposed to checking size then dynamically expanding an array every time a new element is input. I can't get this to compile. I've scoured stack and google and nothing I've found is helping me. Someone mentioned creating an array and using that to be added to the list, but it seems to me i should be able to do this without all that.

I'm trying to get the system to add a string to the list every time a certain result occurs.

For ease of finding the List is called "incorrect"

```
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.util.*;

public class User{
    private String wrongQuestion;       //quiz question
    private String userName;        //store user name
    private String myOutput;        //store output for toString and file write
    private int score;          //store user current score
    private float average;          //store user average score
    private int diffLevel;          //difficulty level
    private int testType;           //last test type
    private int numTests;           //store number of tests taken
    private List <String> incorrect;    //declare list for incorrect answers
    private FileIO uFile;           //declare FileIO object

    public User(String inName) throws Exception
    {
        //local constants
        final int VARIABLE_COUNT = 5;   //loop sentinel
        final int TOKEN_SKIP = 4;       //loop sentinel

        //local variables
        int index;                  //loop index
        int count;                  //loop counter
        String token;               //store tokens from line
        StringTokenizer tokenLine;  //store tokenized line

        //instantiate file object
        uFile = new FileIO (inName);

        //if user exists
        if (uFile.checkUser())
        {
            for (count = 0; count < VARIABLE_COUNT; count++)
            {
                //initialize tokenized line
                tokenLine = new StringTokenizer(uFile.readLine());

                //try to store the variables
                try
                {   
                    //get and store user average
                    //for the first 2 tokens, skip
                    for (index = 0; index < TOKEN_SKIP; index++)
                    {
                        //move to next token
                        token = tokenLine.nextToken();//end for

                        switch (count)
                        {
                            case 1:
                                //store number of tests taken
                                numTests = Integer.parseInt(token);

                                //end case
                                break;
                            case 2:
                                //store difficulty of last test taken
                                diffLevel = Integer.parseInt(token);

                                //end case
                                break;
                            case 3:
                                //store score of last test taken
                                score = Integer.parseInt(token);

                                //end case
                                break;
                            case 4:
                                //store average of tests taken
                                average = Integer.parseInt(token);

                                //end case
                                break;

                            default:
                                break;
                        }//end switch
                    }//end for

                    //store next line
                    token = uFile.readLine();

                    //while there are more lines in the file
                    while (token != null)
                    {
                        //instantiate list for incorrect answers
                        incorrect = new ArrayList<String>();

                        //add line to end of list
                        incorrect.get(token);

                        //store next line
                        token = uFile.readLine();
                    }//end while
                }//end try

                //catch input mismatch exception
                catch (InputMismatchException error)
                {
                    //output error message
                    System.out.println ("This file is not formatted properly." +
                            " Either continue as a new user or log in again");

                    //initialize data to 0
                    average = 0;
                    testType = 0;
                    diffLevel = 0;
                    numTests = 0;
                    incorrect = new ArrayList <String>();
                }//end catch
            }//end for
        }//end if

        else
        {
            //initialize data to 0
            average = 0;
            testType = 0;
            diffLevel = 0;
            numTests = 0;
            incorrect = new ArrayList<String>();
        }//end else

        //close input stream
        uFile.closeFileReader();
    }//end constructor

    public float calcAverage(int newScore)
    {
        //local constants
        //local variables
        float avg;              //store temp average

        /**************Begin calcAverage*********/
        //recalibrate avg for new calculation
        avg = 0;

        //calculate new average test score
        avg = ((average * numTests) + newScore )/(numTests + 1);

        //return average to be stored
        return avg;
    }

    public void updateUser(int newTestType, int newDiffLevel, int newScore)
    {
        //local constants
        //local variables

        /***************Begin updateUser************/

        //update new data after test is taken
        score = newScore;
        average = calcAverage(newScore);
        diffLevel = newDiffLevel;
        testType = newTestType;
        numTests = numTests + 1;
    }

    public void writeFile() throws Exception
    {
        //local constants
        //local variables
        String line;        //current line to write to file
        int index;          //loop index

        /*************************Begin writeFile***************/
        //open output stream
        uFile.openOutput(userName);

        //write user name
        line = "User Name:\t" + userName +"\n";
        uFile.writeLine(line);

        //write number of tests taken
        line = "Tests Taken:\t" + numTests + "\n";

        //write number of tests taken
        line = "Difficulty Level:\t" + diffLevel + "\n";
        uFile.writeLine(line);

        //write score of last test taken
        line = "Last Test:\t" + score + "\n";
        uFile.writeLine(line);

        //write current user average
        line = "User Average:\t" + average + "\n";
        uFile.writeLine(line);

        //for each element in the list
        for (index = 0; index < incorrect.size(); index++)
        {
            //store then write the string
            line = incorrect.get(index);
            uFile.writeLine(line);
        }//end for

        //close file writer
        uFile.closeFileWrite();
    }//end writeFile

    public void storeIncorrect(String inString)
    {
        //local constants
        //local variables

        /************Begin storeIncorrect*************/
        //add formatted question to the list
        incorrect.add(inString);
    }

    public String toString()
    {
        //local constants
        //local variables
        String buildUserName;
        String buildAvg;
        String buildNumTests;
        String buildDiffLevel;
        String buildScore;
        DecimalFormat fmt;      //declare decimal format object

        /****************Begin toString***********/
        //initialize decimal format
        fmt = new DecimalFormat ("0.00");

        //build output strings
        buildUserName = Util.setLeft(20, "User Name:") + Util.setRight(25, userName);
        buildNumTests = Util.setLeft(20, "Tests Taken:") + Util.setRight(18, numTests+"");
        buildDiffLevel = Util.setLeft(20, "Last Difficulty:") + Util.setRight(24, diffLevel+"");
        buildScore = Util.setLeft(20, "Last Score:") + Util.setRight(24, score+"");
        buildAvg = Util.setLeft(20, "Test Average:") + Util.setRight(24, fmt.format(average)+"");

        myOutput = buildUserName + "\n" + buildNumTests + "\n" + buildDiffLevel + "\n" + buildScore + "\n" + buildAvg;
        return myOutput;

    }//Display all users info
}
```

Comment: So which bit is the compiler choking on?

Comment: The `FileIO` class can not be resolved since it is not included in your example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Few comments that might help :

```
// add line to end of list
incorrect.get(token); // <- change this to incorrect.add(token)
```

To iterate thru list use :

```
   for (String item : incorrect) {
       System.out.printlnt(item);
   }
```

Also, you don't need to reinitialize your list as you do multiple times by

```
incorrect = new ArrayList<String>();
```

If you'd like to clear it, you could use `incorrect.clear()`

As you are not interested in Random access (i.e. via index), perhaps you could use `LinkedList` instead of `ArrayList`